# Draw positions/trajectory based on time data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data.

```
Time (ms)| object1(x,y,z) | object2(x,y,z) |  
6        | 1,2.1,0.55     | 13.1,2,1       |  
25       | 0.587,0,0.1    | 1.1,1.5,1      |  
134      | 0.1,0.1,0.1    | 4.1,0.5,1      |
...      | ...            | ...            |
```

I am trying to visualize the trajectories of both object1 and object2 following the timestamp on the left column.
I could visualize the trajectories but with no animation based on the data using the following code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

object1x = list()
object1y = list()
object1z = list()
object2x = list()
object2y = list()
object2z = list()
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        object1x.append(float(row[0]))
        object1y.append(float(row[1]))
        object1z.append(float(row[2]))
        object2x.append(float(row[6]))
        object2y.append(float(row[7]))
        object2z.append(float(row[8]))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot3D(object1x, object1y, object1z, 'red')
ax.plot3D(object2x, object2y, object2z, 'green')

plt.show()
```

Is it possible to animate the trajectories based on the data in Time column ? **Specifically**, I do not want random/predefined update times.

Comment: Would combining a bunch of images into a GIF suffice?

Comment: Yes, I think it would.. But I am not sure how it will work for the large data file with a lot of positions.. and I am not sure how to perform that, because as I said, I want specific time related updates based on the data.

Comment: Not familiar with matplotlib, so can't tell you if animation is possible with it. If there is no way to solve this an alternative might be to use a tkinter canvas, which would be a lot of work as it is not ready-made for graphs. Although it has a lot of flexibility. Not familiar with pygame, but I suspect it might also be an alternative with a lot of work as well.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Thanks, I will try to see if it can be done using pygame

Comment: What is your specific problem with this animation using matplotlib? The plotting itself or the implementation of a timed sequence? If the former: [the matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html) contains a variety of animation scripts that one can adapt. The oscilloscope example shows you for instance how to update the animation when an emitter sends a signal. But I doubt this works in the ms range.